# Why is the middleware stuck in an infinite redirect loop?

Tags: php, middleware

Here is a php middleware (i'm using php v7.1):

```
$slash = function (\Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface $req){
    $url = (string)$req->getUri()->getPath();        
    while($url[-1] === '/')
    {
        $url = substr($url, 0, -1);
    }        
    $response = new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response();        
    return $response->withHeader('Location', $url)
                    ->withStatus(301);
};

$req = \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest::fromGlobals();
$res = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response();

\Http\Response\send($slash($req, $res));
```

This infinitely redirects the requested page and crashes the server.

Can someone help me understand?

Comment: What does `$req->getUri()->getPath()` return? Can you `var_dump` it?

Comment: I assume you are just trying to trim any forward slashes from the end of the string, can't you just do this for the same result? Replace the while loop with this: `trim($url, '/');`

Comment: if it always hits this middleware then you will always 301 them

Comment: $req->getUri()->getPath() return a string. it's not the method I'm looking for but more to understand why it's running in a loop.

Comment: Well, if you can tell me what the value of getPath() is then we can understand why it is running indefinitely. Btw, when you say "indefinitely" do you mean you are always redirected, or the page crahses (infinite loop)?